# Add or delete element when click a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im new in JS. In this case, i want add input book and price in a new row after click + button. So is when i click - button, the input will deleted. Sorry for my bad english.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a81368914c.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Book</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="align-items: center; display: flex">
                <button style="margin-right: 10px;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                <button><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: See an exmaple: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp

Comment: Please learn the language first and show us what you've tried.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 in example my code display block, but in real i have display inline. after i click + button, i want add a new input for book and price in a new row.

Comment: @RahulVerma I will try it. Thanks before

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <div class="container" id="main-element">
        <div class="row row-to-clone"">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Book</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="align-items: center; display: flex">
                <button style="margin-right: 10px;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                <button><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <buttons id="addRow">Add</button>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addRow').click(function(){
          // clone the row  
           const clonedRow = $('.row-to-clone').html()  
          // append to the container
           $('#main-element').append(`<div class="row">${ clonedRow }</div>`);                  
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is not working as expected. Did you tested this one ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping i've updated the answer

Comment: Nice effort - But still not working as expected. Its adding multiple rows after one is added.

Comment: @MUHAMMADSiyab That's not working on me

Comment: I've updated the answer. Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rwvnpad1/

Comment: @MUHAMMADSiyab That's work, thanks. But how to delete the input when i need it ?